# A different perspective of sphere eversion?

Tags: differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, vector-fields, spheres

Usually the process of sphere eversion starts with a sphere whose normals are pointing outward, undergoes some spatial transformation without creasing or pinching (a homotopy), usually using a halfway-model like the tobacco-pouch, ends up as a sphere whose normals point inward. The sphere has been turned inside-out.

Is this equivalent to the following scenario ?

A smooth 3d unit vector field defined on a sphere, which initially points away from the sphere's center (like normals) is continuously and smoothly (without creases or any singularties) transformed into a vector field which points towards the sphere's center (like the inside-out normals).

Does the idea of sphere eversion translate to the described scenario (e.g. by using the normals of the surface during eversion rather than the positions) ? Or is it even the same with a different perspective ? And if so how could the latter be derived from the former ?

Comment: In your scenario, it seems that the sphere itself is not being moved or deformed in any way at all, just the vectors are moving. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in my scenario the sphere is just the domain on which the vector field is defined. So the question is if this vector field, living on a sphere, starting with outward pointing vectors, can be continuously and smoothly transformed into a vector field with inward pointing vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the scenarios are not equivalent, and no such transformation exists.

In fact, the outward normal vector field and the inward normal vector field are not even homotopic to each other through $\mathbb R^3$-valued nowhere zero vector fields on $S^2$, for the following reasons.

Associated to $\mathbb R^3$-valued nonwhere zero vector field $X$ on $S^2$ is the continuous self-map $f_X : S^2 \to S^2$ defined by
$$f_X(p) = \frac{X(p)}{\|X(p)\|}
$$
The function associated to the outward normal vector field is the identity map $I(p)=p$, which has degree $+1$. The function associated to the inward normal is the antipodal map $-I(p)=-p$, which has degree $-1$. But two homotopic nowhere zero vector fields give homotopic self-maps, and degree is a homotopy invariant, so the outward normal is not homotopic to the inward normal through nonzero $\mathbb R^3$-valued vector fields.

Comment: That's what I thought initially and is the reason I was very confused about sphere eversions being possible at all. I imagined my vector field being the normals of the sphere which, during eversion, would smoothly and continuously transform into inside-out normals, while being unit length during the whole process. However this seems to be a misconception. Could you explain (ideally geometrically as I'm not much of an topologist) why sphere eversions are possible (since the process does seem to invert the degree), but the analogy of my vector field being the surface normal's evolution is wrong?

Comment: Let me suggest that you formulate a new question along those lines. I think it can definitely be answered, but it's definitely a more intricate question, and it should stand on its own. Also, it's not a good use for this site to ask further questions buried in comments to answers to old questions.

Comment: You are right. I've put the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669704/a-sphere-can-be-everted-but-a-spherical-vector-field-can-not-why